# Resolving Ninject version conflicts in a plugin architecture

Tags: c#, plugins, ninject

I have an application that supports plugins.  These plugins are sets of DLLs that are loaded into independent application domains.  My primary application looks for classes in these domains (via Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) that inherit from an `IPlugin`and binds each of these to their concrete plugin implementations in the following fashion:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner.From(pluginAssemblies).SelectAllClasses()
      .InheritedFrom<IPlugin>().BindWith<CustomBindingGenerator<IPlugin>>());

//CustomBindingGenerator
public class CustomBindingGenerator<TInterface> : IBindingGenerator
{
    public static readonly string MetadataKey = "PluginKey";

    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        Type interfaceType = typeof(TInterface);
        if (!interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            yield return null;
        yield return (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>)bindingRoot.Bind(interfaceType).To(type).WithMetadata(MetadataKey, type.FullName);
    }
}
```

This all works fine - plugins are loaded and then can be spun up and executed as needed.  My problem started when I tried to provide dependency injection features to the plugins themselves, so that plugins could use constructor injection for their specific application dependencies.  I had each plugin define a `IDependencySpecification` that is passed a reference to same kernel that holds the bindings for all the plugins within the assemblies (i.e., the same `kernel` from above):

```
public class MyPluginDependencySpecification : IDependencySpecification
{
    public void SetupDependencies(IKernel kernel)
    {
         kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();
         ....
    }
}
```

This works great - as long as the version of Ninject that the primary application is using is the same as the version of Ninject that the plugin is using.  Some newer plugins are starting to rely on libraries that require a newer version of Ninject, and when trying to load this `IDependencySpecification`, my main application throws an error saying it doesn't implement the `SetupDependencies` method.

In summary, even though I've tried to isolate my plugins from my application in almost every way (via app domains, etc.), this Ninject reference is leaking through (by necessity) and is now starting to cause version conflict errors.  **Is there a way I can restructure this architecture to avoid this problem and still enable my plugins to specify their own dependency injection bindings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plugins need to use the same version of ninject as the program is using, but rely on features of a different version,.. well that isn't going to work, ever.

There's two things we can change

- make sure the plugin is always built using the same version as the program
- enable the plugin to use any container it likes

Removing that restriction of using the same IoC version could be achieved by implementing something similar to ninject's [child kernel extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel):

The application creates and uses the main kernel.
Each plugin uses it's own IoC. Ninject, Unity, Autofac, you name it.
The IoC is extended in a way, that when itself can't fulfill a request, it passes it onto the application's main kernel.

You'll need to offer an interface to access the main kernel. You'll also need container specific "child kernel" extension implementations which may need to be updated whenever the IoC gets updated.

The child kernel implementation is actually quite small, see https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel/ChildKernel.cs

Comment: The child kernel looks promising - thanks for the lead.